# How do I make one bar narrower in a bar graph in R?

Tags: r, graph

I am very new to R and programming so I apologize for any dumb questions. I have produced this graph:[image: Bar graph] Since each of my treatments has two parts, it made the combined bar width equal to the bar width of the control.

Here is my code:

```
waterhemp_emergence_graph <- 
  ggplot(data = waterhemp_emergence_graph_data, mapping = aes(x = Treatment_Names, y = Total_Emergence, fill = Material))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", position = "dodge")+
  labs(y = "Counts", x = "Treatment", title = "Total Waterhemp Emergence")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray70", "gray20", "gray50"))+
  geom_errorbar(data = df_sig_waterhemp, aes(x = Treatment_Names, ymin = Total_Emergence - se, ymax = Total_Emergence +se),
                width = 0.2, alpha = 0.9, linewidth = 1, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  geom_text(data = df_sig_waterhemp, aes(y = Total_Emergence + se, label = sig$groups),
            position = position_dodge(0.9), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.6, angle = 0)
waterhemp_emergence_graph
```

I tried to use `width=` in `geom_bar()`, but it made every bar weird and out of place instead of just changing the control's width.